# Replacing spaces in image file names

Tags: assets, ce-image

I'm working on an upgrade of an EE2 site to EE6. The site is using Assets and CE Image. A lot of the images that have been uploaded over the years (since 2012) have spaces in the filenames. CE Image used to handle this OK on EE2, but now on EE6, those images aren't being transformed.

I saw elsewhere that adding `url_decode` to the `src` would fix it, but it's not working for me.

I've tried searching for another image resizing add-on but the only one I could find was a [fork](https://github.com/meatpaste/imgsizer) of `imgsizer` and it has the same problem with spaces in file names.

So then I thought about renaming all of the images on the server and updating the `file_names` in the `exp_assets_files` table. But there's a lot of images that have been uploaded twice, some with spaces in the file names, and then others uploaded some time later without. And when trying to run queries on the database, I get errors for `Duplicate entry 'filename.jpg' for key 'unq_folder_id__file_name'`.

Anyone have any advice on this problem? This site has several thousand images on it. :(

Answer (score 0):

> I saw elsewhere that adding url_decode to the src would fix it, but
> it's not working for me.

Might want to try `url_encode`

Other option might be `{my_file:replace find=' ' replace='_'}`

Comment: formatting went wrong i see

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the verge of releasing a new EE5/EE6 add-on (the unoriginally titled **JCOGS Image**) that is a drop-in replacement for **CE Image**. In my testing it works with image filenames that include spaces.  If you DM me either here or via the EE Slack I can maybe set you up with an RC copy if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go for renaming files and file references in the database to prevent similar issues arising later. Cure the problem not the sympton.

Right now you have a couple of good temporary fixes available which will of course work, but it's something you'll always have to "fix".